# Is economics zero sum game in spite of climate change?

Tags: macroeconomics

Governments show so little cooperation in achieving net zero emissions, it makes me think that economic activity is zero or negative sum game when environmental limitations are considered. Is that true?

Comment: No it doesn't. My question is about accounting growth limitations.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko if your question is about accounting then it does not belong on economics.se. Accounting questions are strictly off topic here as explained in our help center here https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. My question assumes economic growth is limited by ecology, does it make it zero sum game?

Comment: I find that you are still not clear enough. In a given time period when the economy grows, it is not zero-sum in the usual sense, see the duplicate question. You can always make up different things to measure; if you are measuring entropy then economic activity will indeed never decrease that. So what exactly are you measuring when you write "zero-sum"?